# Why mysql partitioning has no effect in my case

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I try to test benefits of partitioning in Mysql

I created two tables: one partitioned other not.

Every table has **10M** of records in it.

I want fast querying by **"user_to_id"** column.

Partitioned table (1024 parts):

```
CREATE TABLE `neworder10M_part_byuser` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_to_id`),
  KEY `composite_cover` (`user_to_id`,`user_from_id`,`site_from_id`,`site_to_id`,`created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (user_to_id)
PARTITIONS 1024 */ |
```

Table with clustered key (not partitioned):

```
CREATE TABLE `neworder_10M` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_to_id`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UQ` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

when i benchmark both tables with python script for 1000 reqs:

```
for i in xrange(1,REQS):
    user_id = random.randint(1,10000);
    cursor.execute("select * from neworder10M_part_byuser where user_to_id=%s;" % (user_id))
```

Partitioned table: 22 rps
Not partitioned: 22.7 rps

Why are there no speed benefits with the partitioned table? As I expect smaller data - faster querying.

And explain also shows that partition used:

```
mysql> explain select * from neworder10M_part_byuser where user_to_id=6867;
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | neworder10M_part_byuser | p723       | ref  | composite_cover | composite_cover | 4       | const | 1009 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

but I did not see real speed improve in reality.... what I am doing wrong ?

Tables fill code:

```
def send_orders(cur,users=10000,orders=10000000):
    for i in xrange(1,orders+1): //10000000 rows here
        print i
        from_user = random.randint(1,users)
        to_user = random.randint(1,users)
        from_site = random.randint(1,10000)
        to_site = random.randint(1,10000)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO neworder (site_from_id, site_to_id,user_from_id, user_to_id,created)  VALUES ('%d','%d','%d','%d',NOW());" % (from_user,to_user,from_site,to_site))
```

version of mysql:  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12, for Linux (x86_64). 
Hard drive is ssd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wouldn't expect there to be much difference in performance for the SELECT statements, since the queries are making use of an index range scan, and because the query of the partitioned table is pruning partitions.

Without the partition pruning, we'd expect *slower* performance with a SELECT against the partitioned table. Since that would be 1024 indexes that need to be checked vs. just one index.

The idea that partitioning improves query performance is a fallacy.

Comment: "We wouldn't expect there to be much difference in performance for the SELECT statements," why? as I understand by partition key it possible to determine partition pXXX for O(1) time, and then scan only one determined partition match more faster because it's index contains 10K rows vs 10M rows of non partition full data table index. Why should time scan index on 10K rows equals to index scan on 10M rows?

Comment: Because it's not doing a *full* scan of every index entry. The index is organized in a way that allows the storage engine to very quickly narrow in on the blocks that might contain the entries it's looking for. With the index, there are vast swaths of blocks that it's not possible for the entries to be in. That's how indexes work. In terms of locating the entries, it does not matter if there are 10,000 blocks or 10,000,000 blocks that don't need to be examined. That's why performance is the same.

Comment: " it does not matter if there are 10,000 blocks or 10,000,000 blocks that don't need to be examined. That's why performance is the same"I Mysql " I think this is wrong statement. Index use b+ trees. So time log(N). I just test table for 100K rows and get 1215 rps vs 20 rps on 10M rows table. So search in partition with 10K rows shiuld be much faster then 100K, and much more then with 10M.

Comment: So in fact i got small partition on 10K wich works like one huge table on 10M rows. And it works ~100 times slower then table only with 100k rows! It is confusing

Comment: What's important is the execution plan, and whether that's making *effective* use of an index. There's a *huge* difference between a *full* scan and a *range* scan. I can throw together tests that show horrible performance against tables of 10K rows, and blazing performance against tables of 10M rows. MySQL performance isn't best gauged by "log(N)" operations, or "rows per second". Those overly simplify what is going on, and disregard what *actually matters* in terms of MySQL performance.

Comment: This idea that "partitioning will improve performance of my queries" is a *fallacy*. it's a wrong conclusion drawn from not understanding what *matters* in terms of MySQL performance. it is true that partitioning can bring some big benefits. But those benefits are not usually improving performance of a SELECT query. Rick James has compiled some thoughts here... [http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)  I agree with a lot of what Rick presents.

Comment: There is no full scan of partition, mysql use composite_cover index in my case (you can see explain command above). Indexes inside partition has same structure as in 10M table.

Comment: " But those benefits are not usually improving performance of a SELECT query"  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html  from official docs: "Some queries can be greatly optimized in virtue of the fact that data satisfying a given WHERE clause can be stored only on one or more partitions, which automatically excludes any remaining partitions from the search. "

Comment: Also there is some examples  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html "This section discusses an optimization known as partition pruning. The core concept behind partition pruning is relatively simple, and can be described as “Do not scan partitions where there can be no matching values”. "

Comment: The key there is "*some* queries"... and those queries benefit from partition pruning. There are a lot of queries that don't get any performance benefit. Like the query in the original question, which is making effective use of index. The execution plan for the query is already "pruning" vast swaths of rows. It doesn't matter whether those rows are in the same partition or in different partitions. We can write a query where it does make a difference. But I'm repeating myself. My answer already made this point: *index range scan* is efficient, no performance gain from partitioning.

Comment: You would likely see a performance gain with partition pruning for a query  that was doing a *full scan*. A *full scan* of a 10K row table (or 10K row partition) is going to be less work than a *full scan* of a 10M row table. But with an effective (efficient) *range scan* operation (like the query in the question), it doesn't matter whether the table is partitioned or not.

Comment: As i understand, you say that range scan on 10M rows works as fast as on 10K rows within one table, right?

Comment: How you can explain then such case: i create 1 by 1 copy (with indexes) of TABLE `neworder_10M, named`neworder_100K. Filled it with 100K rows. and test request per seconds on 10M and 100K tables, i got 1000rps vs 20rps. So it 50x faster on smaller table. No matter range scan or full scan, more rows - slower selects. I see it from theory and practice.

Comment: Using the InnoDB storage engine, with the tables and indexes de-fragmented, each table in it's own tablespace (innodb_file_per_table), the bufferpool adequately sized and warmed up, with no query caching (`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`), if both tests are running the same exact queries, over the same range of values, returning the exact same number of rows, we wouldn't expect any significant difference. I suspect your test results are influenced by factors other than the number of rows in the table.

Comment: But that question goes way beyond the question you asked... "why partitioning has no effect in my case". That question has already been answered. If you have a question about setting up a comparison test that compares performance differences due to *only* the number of rows in a table, that's a different question. (It's likely that MySQL is spending more time parsing the SQL text into tokens, performing the syntax check, the semantic check, gathering statistics, evaluating possible execution plans, preparing and returning a resultset, than it spends in actual "execution" of the query plan.

Comment: Thank's for you answers. I found a problem, in case of 10M table my selects were return much more rows (10M/10K users = 1000 per user) in case of 100K table it was only ~10 per select for user. I add "limit 10" to querys and got similar speed in booth cases. With SQL_NO_CACHE I got a little bit performance on partitioned table 1100 vs 1000 rps. As you said in this case index speed as fast as partitioning. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(This is both an answer to the question and a rebuttal to some of the comments.)

If your `WHERE` clause can cause partition pruning to happen, then it can help make a composite index efficient.  Hence, no advantage over non-partitioned table, given that you can choose a better index.

Think of partition pruning as shrinking the BTree depth by 1 level.  But then you have to do the pruning.  Result:  virtually the same cost.  This is my answer to the question of "range scan on 10M rows unpartitioned vs 10K rows in one partition".  (@spencer7593's answers are good, too.)

There are only 4 use cases that I have found where `PARTITIONing` improves performance.  There are in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

`BY RANGE` is the only useful partitioning method.  `BY HASH`, which you are using, seems to be totally useless.  In particular, if you do a range scan on the 'partition key', it will necessarily scan *all* partitions -- no 'pruning' is possible.

It is usually inefficient to put the partition key first in any key.

`UNIQUE KEY id_UQ (id)` -- make that a plain `INDEX` for your non-partition test; it will be more efficient.  And it will be sufficient for handling `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

(Oops, @spencer7593 already said some of these things, and pointed to my blog.  Thanks.  I wrote it because I get tired of repeating myself on the forums.)

Your particular query (`SELECT ... WHERE user_to_id = constant`) is a good way to demonstrate how useless `PARTITIONing` (of any kind) is.  Is that your real query?  You may actually have some other queries that could benefit from partitioning; let's see them.

"50x faster on smaller table" -- caching?  Does the smaller table fit in the buffer_pool, but the bigger one not?  I/O is the biggest factor in performance.

If `WHERE user_to_id = constant` is always in your queries, then have `user_to_id` as the first column in each index (except `INDEX(id)`) in a non-partitioned table.  Think of that as equivalent to 'pruning'.